# Modules 'base' and 'AdharVerificationDynamicFeature' contain entry 'assets/crashlytics-build.properties' with different content

Tags: android, android-bundle, dynamic-delivery

I am generating Signed Build Bundle. Instant App Module is launching perfectly in device but when I am generating Signed Build Bundle I got this error.

'Modules 'base' and 'AdharVerificationDynamicFeature' contain entry 'assets/crashlytics-build.properties' with different content'
In my assets folder 'crashlytics-build.properties' file is not showing.

Error logs :

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':quickRide:packageQrReleaseBundle'.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Modules 'base' and 'AdharVerificationDynamicFeature' contain entry 'assets/crashlytics-build.properties' with different content.

Comment: Any solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

As a workaorund it should be safe to use

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'crashlytics-build.properties'
}
```